# Bypassing Crosdomain error 400 when url has space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using the YQL trick to bypass the crossdomain.xml as explained here [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax) to get card info from http://api.mtgdb.info/ in one of my Unity projects. It works great for cards without spaces in their name, though I get an "error: 400 Bad Request" when there is.

I'm working in C# and I'm using `Uri.EscapeUriString()` to make sure the url is formatted properly (so spaces become %20).

My code:

```
string fields = "name,manacost,convertedManaCost";
string bypassedURL = BypassCrosdomain("http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/" + info.Name + "?fields=" + fields, "json"); //info.Name is the card's name, either "ponder" or "aether vial"
var www = new WWW(url); //This is the Unity equivalent of an ajax GET
yield return www;
```

And the BypassCrossdomain method I made:

```
string BypassCrosdomain(string url, string format) {
    return
        "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'" +
        Uri.EscapeUriString(url) +
        "'%0A&format=" + format;
}
```

So when I try it with the card "Ponder" I get no error, and the bypassedURL is:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/ponder?fields=name,manacost,convertedManaCost'%0A&format=json

On the other hand, when I try "Aether Vial" I get the 400 error, and the url is:

> http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/aether%20vial?fields=name,manacost,convertedManaCost'%0A&format=json

I also tried with several other cards, same result, those without spaces worked, those with didn't.

Any idea why this is, and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to double encode your URL string.

This link works:

[http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fapi.mtgdb.info%2Fcards%2Faether%2520vial?fields=name,manacost,convertedManaCost%27%0A&format=json](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20html%20where%20url=%27http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/aether%2520vial?fields=name,manacost,convertedManaCost%27%0A&format=json)

Notice I changed:

> http://api.mtgdb.info/cards/aether%20vial

to

> http%3A%2F%2Fapi.mtgdb.info%2Fcards%2Faether%2520vial

`Uri.EscapeUriString(Uri.EscapeUriString(url))` should do it.

This should work for your non space names as well.

Comment: That works :D Something I would never have thought of :( Thanks a lot! Why is it that the single-encoding only works for non-space-names?

Comment: You send the URL to yahoo (decoded once), yahoo runs the url (decoded twice).  Its difficult to articulate, but it really is just a coincidence that a non space url works.  The slashes are interpreted properly rather than say escape characters or something.  Spaces wouldnt be your only problem though, any extended character set  object would fail.